# I want some help appearance-wise with Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux

[image: This is the problem]

I want the root@kali user to be colorful like the kali@kali user.
I tried using

```
# export PS1="\e[0;31m\u@\h:\W\$ "
```

but it just kinda broke the entire terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You need to finish color sequence and also escape each `[` and `]`,
and you don't need `export`:

```
PS1='\[\e[0;31m\]\u@\h:\W\$ \[\e[0m\]'
```